# Cyrillic characters are corrupted when using body.getAsync

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've developed a simple task pane add-in for testing Cyrillic characters, but when using body.getAsync() the Cyrillic characters appear to be encoding incorrectly.

Is there a workaround for getting Cyrillic html from an email body? Here’s the code I’m using:

```
var message = Office.context.mailbox.item;
message.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Html, function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        $("#gridResult").html(result.value);
    }
});
```

Here’s the result I get. All the Cyrillic characters are messed up.
[image: Cyrillic character issue in add-in]

### Edit

I ran the code through the Visual Studio debugger and set a break point on the `result.value` prior to invoking `.html()`. The corrupted values are visible. The same thing happens when attaching to the IE Process using F12 developer tools:
[image: Problem on result.value]

Comment: why do you think that getAsync corrupts symbols? maybe problem in `$("#gridResult").html`?

Comment: I created a very similar add-in for Word that does the same thing using the Word 2016 API. I had the same call to `$("gridResult").html()` and it did not corrupt the symbols. So I'm fairly certain the problem occurs at some point during the getAsync() call.

Comment: are you sure that your html where gridResult lives has proper encoding?

Comment: I double-checked and both the JavaScript file and HTML file are both saved with "Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001"

Comment: e-mail message also should have content-type with charset and its better to include meta tag into html code with proper encoding

Comment: Since this is an Outlook add-in in a message read scenario, I'm at the mercy of the sender, so I can't really control the content-type of the email. The HTML page does include the `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` tag.

Comment: We are looking into this. If getting text only works for you can use Office.CoercionType.Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been discovered to be a bug. It will be fixed in an upcoming update for C2R builds. Tentatively, if the build is AFTER 16.0.7117.1000, it should be fixed. This build number is not the exact number that will come up, but when a update comes out, if the number is AFTER that build, the fix should be in.

I can't confirm that this fix will make it until the actual patch comes out though.

The fixes for MSI Outlook 2016 and MSI Outlook 2013 will come afterward. I will update with the KB's and Patches for those updates once they are scheduled to be released.

Comment: Updating this post with the fixed versions. The fixes actually come to the Word binary and NOT Outlook. So the fixed versions for MSI are: 
Word 2016 MSI - 16.0.4470.1000 or later
Word 2013 MSI - 15.0.4868.1000 or later

Once again the version #'s will not align correctly, but anything later than those should have the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue. It was a regression in Outlook Desktop and the fix will get to clients in about two months.
In the meantime the workarounds are calling the API with Office.CoercionType.Text

```
var message = Office.context.mailbox.item;
message.body.getAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, function (result) {
    if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
        $("#gridResult").html(result.value);
    }
});
```

Or using your addin in OWA (Outlook on Web).